# Android Open Accessory device and Windows Phone

Tags: android, windows-phone

It is possible to connect Android Open Accessory device into smartphone with Windows Phone? There are any libs to handle AOA in Windows Phone system?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to use the AOA protocol with windows phone apps

Comment: Maybe it is possible to write such a library?